# Help with deriving an asymptotic expression

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, asymptotics

*Note*: I don't know if this is the best place for this question, because it is very specific. However, I'm not sure of a better place to go (apart from one of the other SE's). If you have a recommendation, I'd love to hear it.

Anyway, here goes:

I'm reading a paper ([Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2945)) in which a critical part is the derivation of a limiting form of a distribution---the relevant equations are (7) and (8). Specifically, given the negative binomial distribution

$$P(s,t|s_0) = \binom{s-1}{s_0-1}(e^{-\kappa t})^{s_0}(1-e^{-\kappa t})^{(s-s_0)},$$

with $s,s_0,\kappa,t>0$, the authors claim that in the limit as $t\to\infty$,

$$P(s,t\to\infty|s_0) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s_0)s_0^{-s_0}}s^{s_0-1}\exp(-s_0s),$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the usual Gamma function. This is precisely a $\mathrm{Gamma}(s_0,1/s_0)$ density in the location-shape parameterization.

I am flabbergasted how they arrived at that. If I try putting the exact distribution $P(s,t|s_0)$ into Mathematica for a given value of $s_0$ and let $t\to\infty$, I decidedly do not observe that asymptotic result; rather, the mean and width of the distribution grow without limit as $t$ does. The result I obtain from taking a limit on the first expression recapitulates what I see in Mathematica, but it looks like

$$P(s,t\to\infty|s_0) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s_0)(e^{-\kappa t})^{-s_0}}s^{s_0-1}\exp({-se^{-\kappa t}})$$

i.e., a $\mathrm{Gamma}(s_0,e^{\kappa t})$ density. If I continue to take the limit to $t\to\infty$, I won't get a distribution at all.

This is a pretty central result of their paper, the paper's now been published in *PRL*, and it would be a pretty severe typo to make, so my first instinct is that I'm misunderstanding what they mean by "asymptotic limit."

> Can you provide any clarification as to why the authors claim the second equation is a limit of the first equation? In what sense is this true? Or what am I missing?

If you agree with me, then I'll feel more confident going to the paper authors and asking for clarification.

Comment: It's definitely some sort of coordinated limit. I'm not sure what they mean by "the continuum limit for $s$", but the two distributions they quote are indeed similar if you make $s_0$ small.

Comment: This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma.E2.80.93Poisson_mixture) seems relevant.